# How to return in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

I currently have an assignment from uni where I have to create a method in Scheme which checks that a list has 2
positive integers (one of which must be between 1 and 3) and a pair.

This list must then be returned. I have no idea how to return this list and I haven't been able to find any helpful resources online.

Here is my code so far:

```
(define (event time id params)
  (if (> time -1)
      (and (or (= id 1) (= id 2) (= id 3))
           )
      (time id params)))
```

Comment: Like most things in Scheme, `if` is an expression that returns a value - the result of evaluating whichever branch (themselves expressions) was selected. For example `(if (positive? 4) 'positive 'negative)` returns `'positive`.

Comment: Nothing in your function works with lists and it assumes that the `time` argument is both a number and a function. That makes no sense.

Comment: It's multiple items under a single identifier I assumed it was a list. The example my uni provided has you enter (event 0 1 (cons 4 5)) and the expected result would be (0 1 (4 . 5)).

Comment: `(define (event time id params)
     (if (> time -1) (and (or (= id 1) (= id 2) (= id 3)))
      '(time id params)))`

I've made some adjustments based on what you said but it produces the same result

Comment: So a function with three arguments that all together have to meet those requirements, not a function that takes a list of values?

Comment: That's how I understand it. It needs to return those values all at once inside a pair of brackets.

Comment: You want `(list time id params)`. `'(time id params)` is a list of three unevaluated symbols - enter it in your interpreter and see. (The backtick is not a general list-creator.)

Comment: Also, the syntax of a conditional is `(if condition true-expression false-expression)`. Your `condition` is `(> time -1)`, the `true-expression` is `(and (or (= id 1) (= id 2) (= id 3)))`, and the `false-expression` is `'(time id params)`.

Comment: Racket has among the best language [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/) you can find. For instance, the Guide's [introduction to pairs and lists](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/pairs.html) and [conditionals](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/syntax-overview.html#%28part._.Conditionals_with_if__and__or__and_cond%29). Look for it in the "Help" menu in Dr Racket.

Comment: In Scheme similar to R and Ruby the last expression that is executed in a function is a return value.